# Object C, Public Functions and Classes

Tags: objective-c, frameworks

Brand new to objective C, have been working on some Swift, converting some reusable files into an importable framework. For swift, I mostly only had to make the classes as well as some functions public so that they could be accessed when imported as a framework, how is this achieved in objective C? (& how are bridging files handled when this is done) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Objective-C, you generally define the `@interface` in a .h file and include any public methods and properties in that .h file. And then to expose those in your framework, you `#include` that .h file in the umbrella header. Or, if including this in Swift project, you'd import that .h file in the bridging header.

Define any private properties or ivars inside a private class extension inside the .m file. That keeps them from being exposed in the .h file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! how does this apply towards @implementation?
Will a class and its methods defined under that be accessible in a swift file if the obj-c file is imported and bridged? Or do I need to somehow publically declare it? The methods are exposed in the h file, so I believe they should be accessible to projects using the framework.

Comment: If you're not talking about frameworks, but just mixed language projects, the .h file effectively _is_ your public interface to your Objective-C code. So, just `#import` that in your bridging header, and those will be exposed to Swift code in that project. There are a few limitations (e.g. if you have variadic methods), but that's basically how it works. For more information, see [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122).